# open new window from firefox extension gets Access denied

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm writing a firefox extension. In this extension i need to open a new tab to display some analytics and data. I have a template html file which i placed in my chrome/content folder.

When i try the following code:

```
var w = content.window.open("chrome://myplugin/content/search.html","My Plugin");
```

i get the following error:

Access to 'chrome://myplugin/content/search.html' from script denied

is there a way to open a new window and to set its URL to a file in the chrome directory?
or is there a better way to load the content into a new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `content` before `window`.  This means that you are using the `content`'s `window` object, which does not have permission to open a chrome URI.  In this case, you just want this:

```
var w = window.open("chrome://myplugin/content/search.html","My Plugin");
```